# Criar um mock para qualquer instância de uma classe

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, moq

Como faço para mockar qualquer instância de uma classe? Gostaria de fazer isso para não ter de mockar um objeto e ter de colocá-lo dentro de uma classe. Exemplo:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TokenTest
{

    GeradorDeToken target;

    [Test]
    public void GeraTokenComSucesso()
    {
        int[] array = { 19, 28, 37, 46, 55 };

        var mockGeradorDeArray = new Mock<GeradorDeArrayParaToken>();

        mockGeradorDeArray.SetupAny(g => g.GeraArray()).Returns(array);

        string tokenEsperado = "1E7C6XB9F8A";

        token = new GeradorDeToken();

        Assert.That(target.GeraToken(), Is.EqualTo(tokenEsperado));
    }


}

public class GeradorDeToken
{
    private int[] arrayNumeros;

    public GeradorDeToken()
    {
        this.arrayNumeros = new GeradorDeArrayParaToken().GeraArray();
    }

    public string GeraToken()
    {
        //Criação do token baseado no arrayNumeros
        return "";
    } 

}

public class GeradorDeArrayParaToken
{

    public virtual int[] GeraArray()
    {
        int[] array = new int[5];

        //Gero numeros randomicos

        return array;
    }
}
```

Ilustrei criando o método fictício SetupAny (não existe na biblioteca Moq). Qual é a forma correta que esse framework resolve essa questão?

Answer (score 3):

Isso não é possível.

Para se testar a classe `GeradorDeToken` usando testes unitários, temos de isolá-la das suas dependências - e isso é feito através de *dependency injection*. Esta injecção pode ser feita através do constructor, propriedades (pouco comum e desaconselhável), ou de parâmetros de um método. Neste caso, parece que precisas de *constructor injection*.

```
public class GeradorDeToken
{
    private int[] arrayNumeros;

    public GeradorDeToken(IGeradorDeArrayParaToken gerador)
    {
        this.arrayNumeros = gerador.GeraArray();
    }

    public string GeraToken() {}    
}

public interface IGeradorDeArrayParaToken {}
public class GeradorDeArrayParaToken : IGeradorDeArrayParaToken {}
```

Se o teu objectivo é evitar repetir a injecção das dependências no teste, podes usar [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) + AutoMoq, uma ferramenta essencial para testes unitários.

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization()));

// Sempre que uma dependência ou um mock precisar de um objecto to tipo `int[]`, a variável `array` será usada.
fixture.Inject(array);

var gerador = fixture.Create<GeradorDeToken>(); // As dependencias serao automaticamente injectadas.
```

Graças á `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`, serão criados automaticamente mocks de interfaces ou classes abstractas, e será feito o setup dos seus métodos/propriedades. Existem também plugins para xUnit e NUnit para facilitar a criação e customização da fixture.

Duas notas acerca da tua implementação:

- Usa uma interface, em vez duma classe com um método virtual.
- O método `GeraArray` devia ser chamado dentro do método `GeraToken` e não no constructor. Caso contrário, chamadas sucessivas ao método `GeraToken` irão retornar sempre o mesmo resultado - não creio que seja esse o comportamento esperado.